# Failed to establish a new connection Discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, python-multithreading, discord.py

Hello in my code it break my request, i tried several time , but after 1-2 hours bot status no longer changed.

i hosting those files in ftp server.

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time
import random
from discord import Game
import math, time
import requests

Client = discord.client
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')
Clientdiscord = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():

client.loop.create_task(scheduler())
print('project ready')

async def scheduler():
while True:
    # sleep until the next whole second
    now = time.time()
    await asyncio.sleep(math.ceil(now) - now)

    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='steady', type=3))
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='ready', type=3))
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='go', type=3))
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='Total Used : '+requests.get('http://username.mydomain/project/total_visit/count.txt').text, type=3))
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='Online : '+requests.get('http://username.mydomain/project/total_online/Live.php').text, type=3))
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='Total Users : '+requests.get('http://username.mydomain/project/total_users/total.php').text, type=3))
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='return again', type=3))

    #i tired to kill all request to start clear again.
    client.logout()
    client.close()
    await asyncio.sleep(20)


    client.run("client_token")
```

> Task exception was never retrieved
>   future:  exception=ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='username.mydomain', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /project/total_visit/count.txt (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))",),)>
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
>       (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
>       raise err
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
>       sock.connect(sa)
>   ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
>       chunked=chunked)
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
>       conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
>       self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
>       self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
>       self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
>       self.send(msg)
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 964, in send
>       self.connect()
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 181, in connect
>       conn = self._new_conn()
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
>       self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
>   urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: : Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
>       timeout=timeout
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
>       _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 398, in increment
>       raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
>   urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='username.mydomain', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /project/total_visit/count.txt (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\bot.py", line 33, in scheduler
>       await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='Total Used : '+requests.get('http://username.mydomain/project/total_visit/count.txt').text, type=3))
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
>       return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
>       return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
>       resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
>       r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
>       raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
>   requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='username.mydomain', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /project/total_visit/count.txt (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> definitely you must to get error,, you made many get.requests.
>
> to slove it, try (Close request) / (restart Bot [background Command])

hm im not good enough, but you can try my step's

1) add Full (urllib3 library)

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time
import random
from discord import Game
import math, time
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
import urllib3
import urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
import certifi
```

2) add (Backgroundworker) Command [will restart your get.request every time.]

```
Client = discord.client
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')
Clientdiscord = discord.Client()

urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl.inject_into_urllib3()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
print('Project Runing..!')


async def task():
await client.wait_until_ready()
while True:

   await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='Loading..!', type=3))

   print('Get_Url-Refresh')
   await asyncio.sleep(1)
   print('Total_Used')
   one = requests.get('http://username.mydomain/project/total_visit/count.txt', timeout=5)
   print('Total_Online')
   two = requests.get('http://username.mydomain/project/total_online/Live.php', timeout=5)
   print('Total_Users')
   three = requests.get('http://username.mydomain/project/total_users/total.php', timeout=5)
   await asyncio.sleep(1)
   print('Refresh Request')

   await asyncio.sleep(10)



   print('Running')
   await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='steady', type=3))
   await asyncio.sleep(5)
   await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='ready', type=3))
   await asyncio.sleep(5)
   await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='go', type=3))
   await asyncio.sleep(5)
   print('Total Used..!')
   await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='Total Used : ' + one.text, type=3))
   await asyncio.sleep(5)
   print('Online..!')
   await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='Online : ' + two.text, type=1))
   await asyncio.sleep(5)
   print('Total Users..!')
   await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='Total Users : ' + three.text, type=3))
   await asyncio.sleep(5)
   print('Refresh..!')

   def handle_exit():
print("Handling")
client.loop.run_until_complete(client.logout())
for t in asyncio.Task.all_tasks(loop=client.loop):
    if t.done():
        t.exception()
        continue
    t.cancel()
    try:
        client.loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait_for(t, 5, loop=client.loop))
        t.exception()
    except asyncio.InvalidStateError:
        pass
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        pass
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        pass


   while True:
   @client.event
   async def on_message(m):
    if m.content == 'die':
        print("Terminating")
        raise SystemExit

client.loop.create_task(task())
try:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(client.start('You_Token_Here'))
except SystemExit:
    handle_exit()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    handle_exit()
    client.loop.close()
    print("Program ended")
    break

print("Bot restarting")
client = discord.Client(loop=client.loop)
```

> Credits to Dev I.A (Gamer's Control).

Comment: i think i got what you mean, cool. Thanks for your help. i will test it,